# Why does my prettier show red color upon saving

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

[image]

So basically I installed prettier in VS Code and enabled the format on paste option in the settings and now I have no clue why these red bars are there in my code..

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Div colors in visual studio code](/questions/69788665/div-colors-in-visual-studio-code). It’s [indent-rainbow](//marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow).

Comment: @SebastianSimon that doesn't fix the question. it's a prettier config issue

Comment: @Claeusdev Which issue? The question is asking why these colored bars show up, not how to fix any issue.

Comment: The colors show up because his current formatting conflicts with the default prettier `tabWidth` config setting.

Answer (score 8):

This problem can be solved by simply re-adjusting the default vscode Tab size configuration. Pressing `cmd ,` (opens User Setting) and then type Tab Size. Set that Tab Size to 2.

This is happening because your default setting is set to 1 Tab = 4 spaces and your prettier is formatting it with 2 spaces.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This just means you have an indentation problem with the prettier config. I think by default prettier expects 2 space indentation. You may want to get into your settings: with `command ,` on MacOS ( not sure the command on other OSs). then search for `prettier space` and you should see something like this. You can play with the value under the 1 `TabWith`.

[image: this image]

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to point out that this can happen if you have an existing file (in my experience it was a .js file) and load prettier after the fact. My prettier wasn't running, so I ran a format file and configured it to run prettier, and even though it was formatting there were red blocks/bars. Restarting VSCode did the trick after that.